# why is the order of tint colour for all the segments reversed in UISegmentedControl? how to correct it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, tintcolor

I can't find what is wrong with the index in this code cuz when I run the simulator all the colour of different elements are reversed?

My ViewController3.h file is as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController3 : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
- (IBAction)segmentControl:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mysegment;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *colorToBeDisplayedInView;



@end
```

here is my ViewController3.m:

```
#import "ViewController3.h"

@interface ViewController3 ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *segments;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end

@implementation ViewController3




- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
//creating textField programmatically
//    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 20)];
//    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
//    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
//    textField.placeholder = @"enter text here";
//    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
//    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
//    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
//    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
//    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
//    [self.view addSubview:textField];

//setting tint color for segments
[[_mysegment.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[[_mysegment.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[[_mysegment.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

[[_mysegment.subviews objectAtIndex:3] setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

[[_mysegment.subviews objectAtIndex:4] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

//to preload everyview before hand
_label.text=@"1";
_image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fruits.png"];
_colorToBeDisplayedInView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/


- (IBAction)segmentControl:(id)sender {
if (_mysegment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
{
    _label.text=@"1";
    _image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fruits.png"];
    _colorToBeDisplayedInView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else if (_mysegment.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
{
    _label.text=@"2";
    _image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"airplane.png"];
    _colorToBeDisplayedInView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
else if (_mysegment.selectedSegmentIndex==2)
{
    _label.text=@"3";
    _image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boat.png"];
    _colorToBeDisplayedInView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
else if (_mysegment.selectedSegmentIndex==3)
{
    _label.text=@"4";
    _image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arctichare.png"];
    _colorToBeDisplayedInView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
}else
{
    _label.text=@"5";
    _image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat.png"];
    _colorToBeDisplayedInView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}
}
@end
```

Comment: i'm not sure if it was already there in the question. here is the link to simulator's screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ9qC.png

Comment: try the same code with only two segment in `UISegmentaionControl`, then see what o/p it gives?

Comment: Your given tint color directly, but this is not good in some conditions. So u set the colors for segments based up on string......

Comment: You try my code.....

Answer (score 0):

The last subview of UISegmentedControl is on left

```
let x = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Red", "Green", "blue"])
x.subviews.last?.frame    //(0, 0, 51, 29)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *value = [yourcolorsSegmentName titleForSegmentAtIndex:yourcolorsSegmentName.selectedSegmentIndex];
NSLog(@"%@", value);
if ([value isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {
//set tint color...
} else if ([value isEqualToString:@"Green"]) {
//set tint color...
}
```

write your code like in this approach ....
this will will give perfect output to you....

Comment: -(void)setSelectedSegmentColor:(UISegmentedControl *)mySegmentedControl{
    for (int i=0; i<[mySegmentedControl.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        if ([[mySegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] )
        {
            [[mySegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor: [UIColor greenColor]];
        }else{
            [[mySegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        }
    }
}

Comment: instead of giving tint colour directly, as you told, i did this:for (int i=0; i<[_mysegment.subviews count]; i++) {
        if ([[_mysegment titleForSegmentAtIndex:i]  isEqualToString: @"Red"]) {
            [[_mysegment.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        } else if ([[_mysegment titleForSegmentAtIndex:i]  isEqualToString: @"Blue"]) {
            [[_mysegment.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        }....

Comment: that means even after comparing all the strings still this doesn't seem to produce any change. its making me feel like either something is wrong with xcode 8.1 or simulator 10.0